# Read, write and print xlsx file in raw resource folder android

Tags: android

I want to make an app which can print bill invoices. I had made a basic layout in xlsx(excel) format leaving the places(cells) for inputting data according to different bills. For that I had put that xlsx file in raw folder and with help of apache poi library, I can easily read the file data. But now i want to update specific cell data in same file(in raw folder) and then print that with help of my app i.e. So that there will be no need to open excel file at all, just fill the information in edittext and press button to print bill. Is there a way to do so? I have browsed through lot of existing stackoverflow threads but none of them are helpful.

Comment: Are the fields just text?  Then just update the field's text.  If you mean including formulas, you'd have to write an entire formula parser-  basically you'd be writing excel.

Comment: No formulae just text. Also i have updated cell value with  setcellvalue function with corresponding row and column but when i am trying to open the file in R.raw.filename with intent, it shows something went wrong. I am not getting how to open xlsx file inraw folder in intent.